# Picklist custom field with grouped values?

Tags: custom-field, picklist

we have a picklist custom field for Opportunity objects where we have all the countries where my company works. Would it be possible to group the values in this field by region or continent? For example: Europe: Germany, Italy, UK, France. LATAM: Brazil, Colombia, Chile. etc.

Thanks.

Comment: I think it is only possible with apex/visualforce.

Comment: Have you tried using Dependent and Controller picklist?

Answer (score 0):

Create two picklists. one with continent/region and other with countries and create picklist dependency between these two.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create 
-one picklist for Region 
-one picklist for Country  
 
and then set field dependency. https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_defining_field_dependencies.htm&language=en_US 
If your requirement is grouping only pertaining to reports then you wont even need a new controlling field, you can directly create bucket on the Country field. 
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_bucketing_adding.htm&language=en_US
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dq1TkYzT-mM

Cheers,